# How to login to a website and auto-refresh page to appear online?

Tags: linux, open-source, javascript, automation, programming

Just as the title suggests. I'd like to be able to login to a website in mind and auto-refresh the page every 30 seconds or so to appear online. However, I would like to do this automatically all the time, like right when I boot up my Arch Linux system. Meaning, in the background, and always running, so on every boot.

I have tried the following with use of a cookie file of when I was logged into the website, but it does not make me appear online.

```
curl -c /path/to/cookies.txt "https://www.website"
```

Is there a program or script of some kind that can help me to achieve this?

Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) is a webdriver that lets you do anything in your browser using scripts.

You can employ it with JavaScript's node.js environment or Python.

There is also their [Selenium IDE](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/), which is a web browser plugin, but it is a bit more limited. It is a bit harder to get timing intervals on it, for instance.